# ImageResource in ClientBundle as real <img> element

Tags: css, gwt, clientbundle

The IE9 does not print background images per default. Is there an option to tell ClientBundle, that all images should be real  elements not fake css-background images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how the `ClientBundle` is generated, and how the image is constructed from the `ImageResource`.

[By default](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/Resources.gwt.xml?r=10282), `ClientBundle`s' `ImageResource`s are generated as `data:` URLs for all browsers but IE6 and IE7, which will use *sprited images* just like an `ImageBundle`. In IE8 and IE9 though, you have to make sure the appropriate permutation is picked up, because they have compatibility modes that could make them appear like IE6 or IE7. Check the mode that's being used in the IE Developer Tools (hit `F12` to open them).

Given an *inlined* or *external* `ImageResource` (one that uses a `data:` or `http://` URL, but not a *bundled*, AKA *sprited* image), you can then use the `ImageResource`'s `getSafeUri()` as the value for the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element.
Unfortunately, GWT will unconditionally use a so-called *clipped image* (the technique used for *bundled* images, based on a CSS background image) when you pass an `ImageResource` to `Image` or `AbstractImagePrototype`. Let's call that a bug.

Comment: What I need is to get rid of the "background" image, see <img onload="" src="clear.cache.gif" style="width: 444px; height: 20px; background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64...

Comment: The question is: *which* "background" image? or in other words: where does it come from? And the answer depends how you create your "image" out of your `ImageResource`.

Comment: You were right, I misunderstood: new Image(resources.Resources.Instance.my_resource().getSafeUri()) does the job.

Comment: D'oh! You were right actually, `new Image(someImageResource)` will create a so-called _clipped image_, using a CSS background. Would you mind filing a bug on the GWT issue tracker so we can plan a fix for a future release? I edited my answer with this information.

Comment: Added a bug to the GWT issue tracker #7403