# GWT canvas and image bundle [understanding questions]

Tags: image, gwt, canvas

I have used this code (kind of tutorial) at http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwt_hmtl5 ... In this code, I used the "Image Scale / Resize" code and I found something that I cannot explain. I mean, instead of using :

```
final Image img = new Image("/img/test.jpg");
```

I have used the client bundle and so the following code:

```
final Image img = new Image(NormalResources.NORMAL_RES_INSTANCE.axl1());
```

And I do not have any error, but the image did not appears. Finally I found the solution with :

```
final Image img = new Image(NormalResources.NORMAL_RES_INSTANCE.axl1().getSafeUri());
```

Do you know the reason why ".getSafeUri()" solves the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [ImageResource in ClientBundle as real <img> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913588/imageresource-in-clientbundle-as-real-img-element/10914280#10914280)

An `Image` created with an `ImageResource` will unconditionally use a *clipped image*, where the image is set as a CSS background image (and the `<img>`'s `src` is a 1×1px transparent GIF). Because the image actually is a blank GIF, painting it to the canvas does nothing noticeable; canvas does not take CSS styles into account.

Using `getSafeUri()` you'll have the `data:` URL of the image, which will be used as the `src` of the `<img>`. No `blank.gif` here, so the image is correctly painted on the canvas.

Note however that `getSafeUri()` won't *work* in IE6 and IE7 by default. If you need to support them, you'll have to annotate your `ImageResource`s with either `@ImageOptions(preventInlining = true)` or `@ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.Both)`. Alternately, you could use `DataResource`s instead of `ImageResource`s.